# How to merge all intersecting (Set a) in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I have a set of sets represented by type `Set (Set a)` from [**`Data.Set`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.6.3).

*I want to union all the member sets whose intersection is not empty.*

Equivalently, I want the components of the graph where there is an edge connecting *x* and *y* if *x* and *y* are in the same Set.

**Examples:**

```
-- import qualified Data.Set as S
ghci> f $ S.fromList [S.fromList [1,2], S.fromList [2,3], S.fromList [5]]
> S.fromList [S.fromList [1,2,3], S.fromList [5]]

ghci> f $ S.fromList [ S.fromList [1,2], S.fromList [2,3], S.fromList [3,4] ]
> S.fromlist [ S.fromList [1,2,3,4] ]
```

What would be an elegant and *performant* solution?

Comment: To be clear: You want the union of all sets with a non-empty intersection?

Comment: ...actually, thinking about it, that sounds just as confusing. :-/

Comment: You might want to define the performance target you're looking for in terms of algorithm complexity!

Comment: Could you provide link to your data set (or something similar), so we can benchmark on our own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### This definition works as expected on complicated `Set (Set a)` constructions

[**Solution:**](http://ideone.com/0UMug3)

```
import qualified Data.Set as S

innerUnions :: Ord a =>  S.Set (S.Set a) -> S.Set (S.Set a)
innerUnions = innerUnion' S.empty
  where
    innerUnion' :: Ord a =>  S.Set (S.Set a) -> S.Set (S.Set a) -> S.Set (S.Set a)
    innerUnion' seta setb
      | S.null setb = seta
      | otherwise   = innerUnion' (S.insert unioned seta) stripped
      where
        (unioned,stripped) = S.foldl f (minElem, setb') setb'
        minElem = S.findMin setb
        setb' = S.deleteMin setb
        f :: Ord a => (S.Set a, S.Set (S.Set a)) -> S.Set a -> (S.Set a, S.Set (S.Set a))
        f (x,xs) y
          | (not . S.null) (x `S.intersection` y) = (x `S.union` y, S.delete y xs)
          | otherwise = (x,xs)
```

A simple fold will not work for complex `Set (Set a)` constructions. A simple fold will produce *incorrect* results

**Example:**

```
ghci> simpleFold $ S.fromList 
         [ S.fromList [1,2], S.fromList [2,3], S.fromList [3,4]
         , S.fromList [5], S.fromList [5,6], S.fromList [6]
         , S.fromList [8,9], S.fromList [0,9], S.fromList [0,1]]
> fromList [fromList [0,1,2,3,4],fromList [5,6],fromList [0,8,9]]
```

**Correct Transformation:**

```
ghci> innerUnions $ S.fromList 
         [ S.fromList [1,2], S.fromList [2,3], S.fromList [3,4]
         , S.fromList [5], S.fromList [5,6], S.fromList [6]
         , S.fromList [8,9], S.fromList [0,9], S.fromList [0,1]]
> fromList [fromList [0,1,2,3,4,8,9],fromList [5,6]]
```

This is because we must consume the input set while building the result set. A fold will not have access to the entire input set during the fold, only access to a single element of the input set at a given time. This means that the transformation function cannot properly consume elements from the input set because it cannot access all elements of the input set. We need to manually write a more complicated fold which *simultaneously* consumes the input set and builds the result set.

The `f` function above performs this simultaneous consumption & construction when applied to a fold.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation. I'm testing this on 200,000 sets of (Set Text) where the inner sets have 1-4 members. Performance still seems to be a major issue.

Comment: @dan `O(n+m)` for intersection checks, and `O(q^2)` checks, where `n` &`m` are the size of member sets and `q` is the size of the set of sets. That makes the time complexity `O(n*q^2)` where `n` is the size of the largest member set and `q` is the size of set of sets. I'm not sure if there is room for improvement... I will think about it!

Comment: The processing run took 21 minutes, reducing 200,000 sets to about 90,000. That may be acceptable.

Comment: @dan There might be a more efficient method by transforming `Set (Set a)` to another data-structure such as `Graph a` or `Set IntSet`. This will require some thought. Must a solution work in general for all parameterized types `a`, or would you like a possible optimized answer for a specific type such as `Text`?

Comment: The `Text` data is a bunch of codes like `B0055URMG0` that can be translated into `Integer` using base36 encoding. So either `Text` or `Integer` would be fine; `Int` is too small.

Comment: @dan Perhaps [**`HashSet`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hashmap-1.3.0.1/docs/Data-HashSet.html) would be a more appropriate data-structure? Try using `Set (HashSet Text)`. Hope that there are no hash collisions! If so, we lose the correctness of the result...

Comment: HashSet is not quite a drop-in replacement. There's no `findMin` or `deleteMin`

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll accept your answer since you've done enough.

Comment: @dan You are correct, but the `findMin` & `deleteMin` functions will operate on the type `Set (HashSet Text)`. `findMin` & `deleteMin` are applied to the outer set `Set (HashSet Text)`, the set of sets, not the member sets which will be substituted for `HashSet Text`. It should still work by modifying the imports and qualifications on some of the Set/HashSet calls. For instance you will need to differentiate between the similarly names functions in the two separate modules!

Comment: How about assigning the Text values unique integer values starting from 1.  From what you say you only have at most 1 million distinct Text values.

Comment: @dan @user5402 You could enumerate all the `Text` values into a `Map Int Text`, then use `Set IntSet` as the data-structure. After doing the intensive `innerUnion` operation, you then translate the `Int`s back to the corresponding `Text` values. That might work better then the current general solution. If you need help with such a process, you should probably ask it as a different question, and include a reference to this question.

Comment: @recursion.ninja Thanks for the suggestions. I might not be able to try them out immediately but I'll post if and when I get around to it.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a link to code which uses a union-find algo.

Answer (score 5):

For the large number of sets you want to merge you want to use a [union find](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/~rs/AlgsDS07/01UnionFind.pdf) algorithm.

You can find Haskell code which implements the union find algorithm here:

https://github.com/erantapaa/union-find-example

Also, for Int sets you'll want to use `Data.IntSet` - it much more efficient.

Previously I wrote the following which doesn't transitively merge sets:

It's a fold:

```
import qualified Data.Set as S
import Data.List (foldl')

mergeSets as = foldl' merge [] as

-- merge one set into a list of sets
merge [] a = [a]
merge (b:bs) a = if S.null (S.intersection a b)
                    then b : merge bs a
                    else (S.union a b) : bs

test = mergeSets [ S.fromList [1,2], S.fromList [2,3], S.fromList [5] ]
```

Comment: The result should be `Set (Set a)`, so you need a `fromList` call

Comment: Thanks. I'm testing this solution on a large set of sets. About 200K sets of 2-4 integers. It's taking a while.

Comment: I think I see the problem. You need to call `mergeSets` again until you get completely disjoint sets. IN that case a completely different algorithm is warranted.

Comment: I have posted such an algorithm consisting of a "simultaneous construction & consumption" fold.

Comment: Nice reference to [**`Data.IntSet`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.6.3/docs/Data-IntSet.html). I often substitute `(Enum a => Set a)` with  `IntSet a` by using the `fromEnum` call. This can save *a ton* of space and result in *much* better access times.